# Chrome extension background property and popup.html wont work together

Tags: google-chrome-extension, background, popup

In my manifest.json when i add in the background property the popup doesnt work (when i click on the extension nothing happens) but when i get rid of the background property the popup starts to work. I have no idea why that is. I am posting the manifest below:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test blocking of 9gag",
  "description": "my test shittt",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
 "permissions": ["webRequest","webRequestBlocking","*://9gag.com/*"]
  ,
 "background": {
  "persistent": true,
   "scripts": [ "block.js" ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Added other files
background script : block.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {redirectUrl: "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A3P-CvVSIyo/USzTbs0RRBI/AAAAAAAAALg/x47zbfBbYtw/s1600-rw/y-u-no-work"}
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]);
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<div id="result"></div>
<p>Test.</p>
<p>test123</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be a problem with you trying to indiscriminately redirecting every request to that url without requesting host permissions for `<all_urls>` try limiting it to 9gag or expanding your host perms and see if it clears up the error that is likely in your background page console.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should write it as an answer in case someone else has the same issue. The `webRequest` api requires host permissions for every url's request it is listening to. Since you wish to alter `<all_urls>`, then simply add that to your permissions field like this:

```
"permissions": ["webRequest","webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"]
```

Although, in practice it is better to only request permissions for hosts that you actually need. In this case 9gag. Changing your filter would work as well.

```
{urls: ["*://9gag.com/*"]},
```